# Alkaline Ester Hydrolysis Reaction

Tags: acid-base, hydrolysis, esters

In an ester hydrolysis reaction using a dilute base what is the pH change before and after the reaction occurs. In this reaction I want to react methyl ethanoate with dilute sodium hydroxide. I want to know if the pH of the solution will change after I add the ester to the base.
If it doesn't, is there a reaction I can do with esters that will result in a pH change?

Comment: Assuming this is in water. The pH shouldn't change much because the pKa of alkoxides in water are pretty much the same as that of water itself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for replying. Is there some reaction that you can do with esters that will allow a change in pH?

Comment: The pH will definitely change... Write out the mechanism to see why.

Comment: Just any reaction where I can see a pH change that I can use with an ester. And how would I write out the mechanism? I am a beginner with organic chem, are there any websites you could recommend to be able to write out the mechanism?

Comment: Looking at the mechanism properly. At the start when it is only dilute NaOH, it is pH basic. But when I add the ester, it will react and form an alcohol and carboxylic acid, which is acidic. So wouldn't the pH of the final solution be lower than the start?

Comment: My bad. Jerepierre is correct. pH would definitely go down. But it wouldn't be a carboxylic acid. You would still end up on with pH>7.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. Would you also be able to tell me where I can find an experimental setup for this type of reaction so I can actually do it? I am having a bit of ytrouble finding something online with actual measurements for things.

Answer (score 2):

Alkaline hydrolysis of ester:

> $\ce{RCOOR' + OH- -> RCOO- + R'OH}$

Almost all organic acids are weak acids:

> $\ce{RCOO- + H2O <<=> RCOOH + OH-}$

Therefore, a lot of $\ce{OH-}$ is consumed during the esterification, with the product $\ce{RCOO-}$ generating little $\ce{OH-}$.

There is a net consumption of $\ce{OH-}$, making the solution more acidic, lowering the pH.